# How do I use npm install && npm run to rebuild a page on a website (coding challenge)

Tags: node.js

I have a coding challenge where I am required to rebuild a website page. I finished that just using HTML and CSS but my interviewer is giving me these instructions for bonus points but I'm not sure what he wants me to do since I don't have experience in node:

**If you use node and I can run it with npm install && npm run. If you go this route, do NOT send the node_modules folder.f you use a preprocessor (i.e. SASS or LESS), please send those along with the compiled version. I should not have to compile your stylesheets.**

What does he mean exactly? I'm a beginner to node and I tried googling some information, but don't see where I can learn more about npm install and npm run. Can someone explain in a nutshell what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

In node.js you can install node programs/modules using NPM. NPM is a package manager for node.js.

So what he is trying to tell you, if you install a modules/program in your code from NPM to solve this coding challenge, don't send him the installed modules files. he can know the modules that you installed from the **package.json** **which is the file that give him the information about all the required modules to run the application**. Then he can use npm commands to install all the dependencies that are listed in package.json.

The Other point is SASS or LESS which is a dynamic stylesheet techniques to generate your css files. so if you used this techniques just send him the compiled css files.

Comment: Ahmand, where can I find a step by step tutorial on how to do this? Right now I have my html and css files done, can you list out the steps I would have to do to get this done?